# How to solve problems in elementary number theory?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

I have studied and solved almost all of Elementary Number Theory by David M. Burton. Yet, tough problems in NT from Olympiads seen unapproachable to me. What should I do? What should I study? I feel so frustrated! Please help me! Thank you! :)

Comment: Why don't you ask the questions here.....first think hard on the problem for at least 2 days...if you don't get it then search for the question here...someone might have already asked a similar question....if not..then ask the question and also show your working and your thought process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Kind of problems need something more, a lot of special training, there are some trics and constructions, it's no easy to everyone. Somethimes I get stuck for 3-4 days in a problem, somethimes i can't solve, there are a problem that i can't make a elegant solution: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225548/maxa-1-in-x-n-n-in-mathbbn

Comment: I am strong in Geometry, Analysis,etc but NT eludes me. What book should I study next in NT?

Comment: what NT have you studied? There are Analitic NT, algorithmit NT, algebraic NT. You can look Vinogradov- theory of numbers T, Hardy-an introduction to theory of numbers , or Tom Apostol- Introduction to analityc theory of numbres.

Comment: Just elementary NT! Need books that will help me for IMO. :)

Comment: do you have special training? try checking the solved problems of lasts IMO and rescate the "tricks" and if you cant solve any problem, ask here ;)

Comment: And try solving as many problems as possible. Try some NT Marathons. Make use of resources as much as possible. AoPS is a great place for contest preparation and info regarding training.

Comment: i forget, you should look for Titu Andreescu book's